# deploying simple contract on quorum 7nodes example

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, quorum

I am trying to deploy contract with privateFor tag in migration and for set function same as shown in truffle quorum 7node example.
started nodes with these commands

```
./raft-init.sh
./raft-start.sh
```

nodes started fine, but when I tried to deploy contract with truffle on localhost:22000, truffle showing an error:

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 22000
    - network_id > *
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

please let me know what seems to be the problem, Is there any step missing?

note :I thought there is a problem with rpc connection in geth. but I dont now how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to check whether you can connect directly to geth with 'geth attach qdata/dd1/geth.ipc'.
If that fails then your geth node is possibly not running. You can check with 'ps -ef | grep -i geth'. Take a look in the log file for any errors (qdata/logs/1.log).
fyi here is the truffle config I have:

```
        node1: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 22000,
            network_id: '*',
            gas: 6000000,
            gasPrice: 0,
            type: "quorum"
        },
```